# Problema com CSS e ASP Button

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp

Estou a tentar pôr um botão `ASP` com uma determinada `class CSS` mas não estou a conseguir colocar o botão `ASP`  a funcionar de acordo com o `CSS`.

Se o botão for `HTML` dá sem problema.

**Código CSS**:

```
.images_1_of_5 .button{
    margin-top:.3em;
    line-height:1.9em;
}
.images_1_of_5 .button a{
        padding: 8px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: url(../images/button3.gif) left top repeat-x;
        border: none;
        font: bold 12px "Arial"!important;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
.images_1_of_5 .button a:hover{
      background-position: left bottom;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
```

**Código HTML com botão ASP**:

```
<div class="grid_1_of_5 images_1_of_5">
<div class="button">
<a><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></a></div>
```

**Sem botão ASP**:

```
<div class="grid_1_of_5 images_1_of_5">
<div class="button"><span><a href="singlepage.html">Ver Detalhes</a></span></div>
```

Comment: E se você usar `cssClass` direto no botão e criar uma classe específica ?

Comment: Já tentei, mas não consegui, poderei estar a fazer algo mal, poderia exemplificar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="idButton" runat="server" CssClass="classButton" CausesValidation="False" Text="Button" />`

```
.classButton{
        padding: 8px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: url(../images/button3.gif) left top repeat-x;
        border: none;
        font: bold 12px "Arial"!important;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.classButton:hover{
      background-position: left bottom;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
```

Note que troquei a sintaxe do seu **Asp:Button** para **Asp:LinkButton**.